# how to send hash maps to run method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, arguments

I am writting java client and server in which I want to maintain hash map between multiple threads.I have written following code but I am unnable to access updated code in run method.Also are concurrent hash maps more useful in such scenario? Any tips will be very helpful.Thanks in advance

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


public class JavaServer extends Thread{

    //To access packet in run method
    static byte[] receiveData=new byte[2048];
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
            receiveData.length);
    JavaGenericCryptoLibrary cryptoObj=new JavaGenericCryptoLibrary();
    static JavaBuisinessFunctionsServer objB=new JavaBuisinessFunctionsServer();
    static DatagramSocket ds;
    static Map<String,String>  hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    public JavaServer(DatagramSocket ds, Map<String,String> hm1) {
        JavaServer.ds=ds;
        JavaServer.hm=hm1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        JSONObject receivedObj = null;
        try {
            // Port Number for login
            int serverPort_login = 3964;
            int serverPort_requests = 3764;

            DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverPort_login);
            DatagramSocket serverSocket_clients = new DatagramSocket(serverPort_requests);
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                    receiveData.length);

            hm.put("Current_User","Blank");
            // Server initialized
            System.out.println("Intilized Server");
            while(true)
            {   
                hm.remove("Current_User");
                hm.put("Current_User","Blank");
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                hm=(HashMap<String, String>) objB.login(serverSocket,receivePacket.getAddress(),receivePacket.getPort(),(HashMap<String, String>) hm);
                System.out.println("current user at server"+hm.get("Current_User"));
                //JavaServer r = new JavaServer(serverSocket_clients,hm);
                System.out.println("before thread:"+JavaServer.hm.get("Current_User"));
                System.out.println("before thread:"+JavaServer.hm.get(JavaServer.hm.get("Current_User")));

                new JavaServer(serverSocket_clients, hm).start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Server" + e);
        } 
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            // Packet received on the thread.
            // Respective function will be initialized 
            JSONObject online_user_json_obj=new JSONObject();
            while(true)
            {   
                ds.receive(receivePacket);
                JSONObject t=cryptoObj.readRecievedPacket(receivePacket);
                switch((String)t.get("Command"))
                {
                case "Chat":

                    break;
                case "Logout":

                    break;
                case "List":

                    Enumeration<String> online_users = cryptoObj.get_Online_Users();
                    online_user_json_obj.put("List", online_users);
                    String user=hm.get("Current_User");
                    System.out.println("user "+user);
                    String ip_port=hm.get(user);
                    System.out.println("ip_port"+ip_port);
                                    //Here I amnot getting updated values
                    String[] ip_port_arr=ip_port.split(" ");
                    System.out.println(ip_port_arr[0]);
                    InetAddress ia=InetAddress.getByName(ip_port_arr[0]);
                    int port=Integer.getInteger(ip_port_arr[1]);
                    ds.send(cryptoObj.udpPacketGenerator(online_user_json_obj,ia,port));
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Rogue Data");
                    break;
                }

            } 
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use RMI ?

Comment: Will you have concurrent modification? If so, `ConcurrentHashMap` might be useful.

Comment: Actually I am new to this. Not sure how to implement either RMI or  concurrent modification. I am currently writing java server and client using socket. Server will have n number of requests and each time if user is authenticated server will add entry in hash map. So in this scenario what will will be more helpful and how to implement it?

Comment: or can I update above code to work well as per my requirement?

Comment: See my answer below on wait() and notifyAll(). Please let me know if you need help with how to code this and I'll check back in later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConcurrentHashMap will be helpful in your case. Else you can use a lock and guard the access to the hashMap that way, the changes will be visible to all threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at a book like Lea's Concurrent Programming in Java. One thread needs to become the object's monitor. Then all the servers can call a wait() on the HashMap and be woken up after the monitor is notify(). You then call notifyAll() from the HashMap's monitor thread when the HashMap is modified. See java.lang.Object notify(), wait() and notifyAll() for information on how to set this up.

Basically, you'll have to designate one thread the monitor of the object. Then, when that thread is woken by notify() you'll notify all the other threads.

Comment: This is only one of the possible approaches. It's a kind of low-level approach. There are others.

Comment: True but not a lot of code to implement for a low-level approach.

Comment: Thanks all. I will implement above approach.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help. And if you find that it works, would you mind accepting this as the correct answer?